# How to write this query to show result for one column based on specific values of another column?

Tags: sql

My database schema is like following

table - X has following 3 columns docid(document id), terms(terms in document), count(number of terms of occurence of the term for specific docid)

```
docid
terms
count
```

How to write a query to find documents which contains both the words 'hello' and 'hi' in terms column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select DocId
FROM TableName
where Term IN ('hello','hi')
Group by DocId 
Having Count(*)=2;
```

a `DISTINCT` keyword in `HAVING` clause is much preferred if `Term` is not unique on every `DocID`

```
Select DocId
FROM TableName
where Term IN ('hello','hi')
Group by DocId 
Having Count(DISTINCT Term)=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
Select DocId,Count(term) from Table Name
where Term='hello' or Term='hi'
Group by DocId 
Having Count(Distinct term)=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT docid, COUNT(term)
FROM tablex
WHERE term IN('hello', 'hi')
GROUP BY docid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT term) = 2;
```

See it in action:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85f1b/1).